# unit test Error: could not decode result data

Tags: unit-testing, solidity, ethers.js

i am running into this issue when i carry out this unit test on this smart contract

```
const { network } = require("hardhat");
const {
  networkConfig,
  developmentChains,
} = require("../helper-hardhat-config");
require("dotenv").config();
//const { verify } = require("../utils/verify ");

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
  const { deploy, log } = deployments;
  const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();
  const chainId = network.config.chainId;

  let ethUsdPriceFeedAddress;
  if (chainId == 31337) {
    const ethUsdAggregator = await deployments.get("MockV3Aggregator");
    ethUsdPriceFeedAddress = ethUsdAggregator.address;
  } else {
    ethUsdPriceFeedAddress = networkConfig[chainId]["ethUsdPriceFeed"];
  }
  log("----------------------------------------------------");
  log("Deploying FundMe and waiting for confirmations...");
  const fundMe = await deploy("FundMe", {
    from: deployer,
    args: [ethUsdPriceFeedAddress],
    log: true,
    // we need to wait if on a live network so we can verify properly
    waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
  });
  log(`FundMe deployed at ${fundMe.address}`);

  if (
    !developmentChains.includes(network.name) &&
    process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY
  ) {
    await verify(fundMe.address, [ethUsdPriceFeedAddress]);
  }
};

module.exports.tags = ["all", "fundme"];
```

```
const { assert, expect } = require("chai");
const { deployments, ethers, getNamedAccounts } = require("hardhat");

describe("FundMe", function () {
  let fundMe;
  let mockV3Aggregator;
  let deployer;
  const sendValue = ethers.parseUnits("1"); // the converts the 1 into 1eth
  beforeEach(async () => {
    // const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
    // deployer = accounts[0]
    deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer;
    await deployments.fixture(["all"]);
    fundMe = await ethers.getContractAt("FundMe", deployer);
    mockV3Aggregator = await ethers.getContractAt("MockV3Aggregator", deployer);
  });

  describe("constructor", function () {
    it("sets the aggregator addresses correctly", async () => {
      const response = await fundMe.getPriceFeed;
      assert.equal(response, mockV3Aggregator.address);
    });
  });
  describe("fund", function () {
    it("fails if you dont send enough ETH", async () => {
      expect(fundMe.fund()).to.be.revertedWith("You need to spend more ETH!");
    });
    it("Updates the amount funded data structure", async () => {
      await fundMe.fund({ value: sendValue });
      const response = await fundMe.addressToAmountFunded(deployer);
      assert.equal(response.toString(), sendValue.toString());
    });
  });
});
```

these is my package.json

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers": "^2.0.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers": "^3.0.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers": "^1.0.8",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^3.0.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-verify": "^1.0.0",
    "@typechain/ethers-v6": "^0.4.0",
    "@typechain/hardhat": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.0",
    "@types/mocha": ">=9.1.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "ether": "^0.0.9",
    "hardhat": "^2.9.3",
    "hardhat-gas-reporter": "^1.0.8",
    "solidity-coverage": "^0.8.1",
    "ts-node": ">=8.0.0",
    "typescript": ">=4.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chainlink/contracts": "^0.3.1",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "npm:hardhat-deploy-ethers",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^3.1.7",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.2",
    "dotenv": "^14.2.0",
    "ethereum-waffle": "^3.4.0",
    "ethers": "^6.0.0",
    "hardhat-deploy": "^0.11.34",
    "solhint": "^3.3.7"
  }
}
```

i get this error message

```
yarn run v1.22.19
warning package.json: No license field
$ /Users/eric/Documents/hardhat/Fund-me/node_modules/.bin/hardhat test --grep 'amount funded'

  FundMe
    fund

      1) Updates the amount funded data structure


  0 passing (688ms)
  1 failing

  1) FundMe
       fund
         Updates the amount funded data structure:
     Error: could not decode result data (value="0x", info={ "method": "addressToAmountFunded", "signature": "addressToAmountFunded(address)" }, code=BAD_DATA, version=6.7.0)
      at makeError (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:685:21)
      at assert (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:702:25)
      at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/abi/interface.ts:916:15)
      at staticCallResult (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:332:35)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at staticCall (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:289:24)
      at Proxy.addressToAmountFunded (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:337:41)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/unit/FundMe.test.js:30:24)



error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

thank you in advance

i have done the following

downgraded both ethers and hardhat and still running into this error

i know the issue is comming from the addressToAmountFunded(deployer)

can someone please explain what can be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in **beforeEach** as here you are using ethers.getContractAt() method and in getContractAt, the **first argument** should be the **contract name** which is **FundMe** in your case, and the **second argument** should be the **address at which your contract is deployed**, but you have passed the **deployer** address here which is wrong.
You can use the below code to make it work:

```js
 beforeEach(async function () {
    deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer;

    await deployments.fixture(["all"]);
    const fundMeContract = await deployments.get("FundMe");
    fundMe = await ethers.getContractAt("FundMe", fundMeContract.address);

    const mockV3AggregatorAddress = await deployments.get("MockV3Aggregator");

    mockV3Aggregator = await ethers.getContractAt(
      "MockV3Aggregator",
      mockV3AggregatorAddress.address
    );
  });
```